# After transferring my project from my PC to a laptop a piece of code doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity and am following a guide. In the game you have to fly a rocket through an obstacle course. This is my code for the movement of the rocket:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] float mainThrust = 100f;
    [SerializeField] float rotationSpeed = 50f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ProcessThrust();
        ProcessRotation();
    }

    void ProcessThrust()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Boost
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * mainThrust * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void ProcessRotation()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            //Rotate left
            ApplyRotate(rotationSpeed);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            //Rotate right
            ApplyRotate(-rotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    void ApplyRotate(float rotationPreFrame)
    {
        rb.freezeRotation = true; // freezing rotation so we can manually rotate
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 1 * rotationPreFrame * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.freezeRotation = true; // unfreezing rotation so the physics system can take over
    }
}
```

For some reason I can't fly the rocket, only rotate left and right. Got any idea why?

Comment: What type of IO are you using for the controls?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I see it now, sorry. So the rocket rotates when you press the right or left arrow but the thrust is not working when you press spacebar?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and setting breakpoints to see what is happening when you press space bar? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

I would put a breakpoint inside `void Update()` on `ProcessThrust()` and inside `void ProcessThrust` on your if statement and see if the input value matches `KeyCode.Space` then step through the code.

Comment: I removed Time.deltaTime and it worked, but that wouldn't be framerate independent right? So I put it back and changed the mainThrust value to 2000 and it worked. But why didn't it work with the orignal value of around 180? Shouldn't it be framerate independent?

Comment: Looking at the documentation `Time.deltaTime` is NOT [framerate independent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). To ignore differences in framerate it appears you either want to use a `FixedUpdate()` method or `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. [See documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have a rigidbody applied on the object?

If so, check that inside *Project settings > Player > Active input handling* is set to **BOTH**.

Anyway, try to change your input system to the new one:
https://learn.unity.com/project/using-the-input-system-in-unity